# how to develop graphics in android application

Tags: android, graphics

i have just gone through making some basic apps on android and was wondering
how to get graphics on the screen....and how to go about 
developing something like the tom cat application first and then go onto games...
could you'll plz point me in the right direction as to how to approach this...
and wat all it requires?

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend you read [through this series of tutorials](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html) to get you started with drawing 2D graphics on Android for games.

Comment: the link is broken, can you write down the names of the tutorials for reference.

Comment: @pallavi web archive has a copy of it: http://web.archive.org/web/20121109162604/http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html

Answer (score 3):

The Android API "Lunar Lander" got me started on 2D gaming. Of course, it's now apparent that there are flaws in it the demo, but still.. It gives you an idea of how to draw objects on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you are new to development, if yes: you should read more basic
Everything is on android development official site.

Ho through basic and learn math then you will be able to do complex apps like Tom cat